# Round Submit Button on iPad

Tags: html, css

I have a problem on my website [enter link description here](https://mardeipoeti.com) There is an INPUT of the Submit type that display perfectly everywhere except on the iPad where it is round.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mzfxm.png)

I have tried to reset browser properties but nothing works

```
input[type="submit"], input, textarea, button {
-webkit-appearance: none!important; /*Safari/Chrome*/
-moz-appearance: none!important; /*Firefox*/
-ms-appearance: none!important; /*IE*/
-o-appearance: none!important; /*Opera*/
appearance: none!important;
-webkit-border-radius: 0!important;
```

}

Comment: `border: 0;` should help.

Comment: Could you add the CSS applied to the button?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help, but you have not done just plain 'border-radius: 0;'.

Comment: Oh my god, it was a very simple problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the html element itself by specifically altering the css instructions by class or unique id?

```
input[type="submit"], input, textarea, button {
-webkit-appearance: none!important; /*Safari/Chrome*/
-moz-appearance: none!important; /*Firefox*/
-ms-appearance: none!important; /*IE*/
-o-appearance: none!important; /*Opera*/
appearance: none!important;
-webkit-border-radius: 0!important;
```

Should be alterable to

```
div.search_room > input#box_submit_button.button {
   -webkit-appearance: none!important; /*Safari/Chrome*/
    -moz-appearance: none!important; /*Firefox*/
    -ms-appearance: none!important; /*IE*/
    -o-appearance: none!important; /*Opera*/
    appearance: none!important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0!important;
}
```

more specific approach. In addition you can focus only on the webkit instructions seeing its a ipad situation / safari form result.

Comment: It is already sufficiently specific to override the user agent stylesheet though.  Not least due to the `!important`